# phpMyAdmin: Cannot redeclare class Application_Octetstream_Download

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just recently ran into this error with phpMyAdmin:

`Cannot redeclare class Application_Octetstream_Download`

I was trying to add a table to a database and I got that error. I am running Apache with MariaDB, the latest version of phpMyAdmin and PHP 5.4.36.

Solutions?

Comment: You might want to add the phpMyAdmin version number - "latest" just does not make any sense anymore, now, 4 months after posting this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when I only replaced files by copying new version to a phpMyAdmin folder already in use. **Solution is to put files from updated version into a new and empty folder.**